# How to delete intersected particles

Tags: particles

As per my previous post, I am following Blender Guru's donut tutorial.

To improve realism, **is there a way to delete particles** (the sprinkles in this case) **that have intersected?**

Comment: Possible (untested) answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15d9yWT5A4Y